# What's the point of passing require function to require.ensure?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I try to understand how `require.ensure()` actually works. Particularly, why do we need to pass `require` to the callback of `require.ensure()`?

## 1. This works:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    require.ensure([
        "./mod.js" // files that chunk will contain
    ], function(require) {
        console.log(require("./mod.js")); // returns result of mod.js
        }, 'mod'); // name of chunk file
```

However, if I change the name of the parameter `require` to `req`,

## 2. This doesn't work:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    require.ensure([
        "./mod.js" // files that chunk will contain
    ], function(req) {
        console.log(req("./mod.js")); // should return result of mod.js, but doesn't
        }, 'mod'); // name of chunk file
```

it will throw an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)
```

which comes from this line:

```
// Execute the module function
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

**Why example #2 doesn't work?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you look at the [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#defining-a-split-point) you'll find that you don't need to receive the require function as a callback parameter.

```
require.ensure(["module-a", "module-b"], function(/* this should be empty */) {
   var a = require("module-a");
   // ...
});
```

So, you're probably receiving nothing in "req" - that's why it's undefined -, and you should use "require" because, well, that's the function you need to call.

Comment: So in #1 this argument is ignored because the priority has the other `require`. But it's not true that `req` in #2 is empty. Both `require(s)` are same functions, only the one in #2 is probably bound to seperate context because it throws an error at modules[moduleId]. And I'd love to know why, because I get the exact same error in #1 when I serve my JS by `webpack-dev-server` - there is something shady going on with that `require`.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with static analysis? Sorry I couldn't help... =/

Comment: Are you using babel? There's a disussion on github (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1685) where some folks have solved this by using the babel-plugin-add-module-exports (https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports)

Comment: No, I've fixed it, it crashed because my publicPath was not matching dev server's client path. But as of this require parameter I still don't get it - in some examples (like you posted) they don't use it and in [others](http://jonathancreamer.com/advanced-webpack-part-2-code-splitting/) they do.